# Why am I always getting "PubnubException"?

Tags: php, laravel, pubnub

I trying to build a server using laravel and pubnub, but the page always show a blank page, and after i look at the response it seems there is something wrong on pubnub.php (http response : 500)

and after I open dist/pubnub.php, it always said:

> "PubnubException in Pubnub.php line 93: Missing required $subscribe_key param"

and after some searching, I found that I need to get a pub_key and sub_key, now for the question, what should I do to fix this error? how to init the pubnub? and of course I have search something about this but all of them still lead me to a dead end.

Comment: have you even tried to read the documentation?

Comment: If you are using a package for this purpose in Laravel, let me know. I can help configuring keys for that package.

Comment: I have read the documentation, but still cann't figure out what should i do.

Answer (score 1):

Register at pubnub.com, get your keys and use them when init:

This is the format:

```
$pubnub = new Pubnub($publish_key, $subscribe_key, $secret_key)
```

For more details:
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/php/pubnub-php-sdk#init

Comment: Well i'm sorry but i am still really new to pubnub and laravel, so where do i put that?

Comment: This is more of a php/laravel issue I believe as the PubNub part is just php code. But see the full PubNub tutorial here: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/php/data-streams-publish-and-subscribe (not Laravel focused).

Comment: For PubNub Laravel example, see this third party github repo: https://github.com/LogikIO/pubnub-laravel